# FTP Hostname and Username combied "|" (IIS windows server 2012 r2)

Tags: iis, windows-server-2012-r2, ftp, iis-8

I have setup a working FTP site but a specific setup is being asked...

This is  credentials I use to login to my FTP (This works just fine)

Host: "Myhostname"
Username: "MyUserName"
Password: "MyPassword"
Port: 21

What I am being told is that we need the credentials to be

Host: "Myhostname"
Username: "Myhostname|MyUserName"
Password: "MyPassword"

Of course when I try to use this type of Username I am not allowed access to my FTP

Is there a way to enable the "|" into the username?

Answer (score 0):

You only need that complex user name when you enabled FTP virtual host names.

More information can be found from [this Microsoft article](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/publish/using-the-ftp-service/using-ftp-virtual-host-names-in-iis-7)